# Understanding variable_scope and name_scope in tensorflow and variable sharing

Tags: tensorflow

I'd like to share variables between two subgraphs. More precisely, I'd like to do the fowolling operation : given 4 tensors `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` and a weight variable `w`, compute `W*a`, `W*b`, `W*c`, `W*d` but in different subgraph. The code, I have is as follow :

```
def forward(inputs):
  w = tf.get_variable("weights", ...)
  return tf.matmult(w, inputs)

with tf.name_scope("group_1"):
  a = tf.placeholder(...)
  b = tf.placeholder(...)
  c = tf.placeholder(...)

  aa = forward(a)
  bb = forward(b)
  cc = forward(c)

with tf.name_scope("group_2):
  d = tf.placeholder(...)

  tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variable()
  dd = forward(d)
```

This example seems to run but I'm not sure whether the variable `W` is reused especially inside the `group_1` When I add `tf.get_variable_scope.reuse_variable()` I got an error saying that there's no variable to share.
When I visualize the graph in tensorboard, I do have several `weigths_*` inside the `group_1` subgraph.

Comment: It really helps to provide working code rather than skeleton code (containing typos, such as `matmult`). Moreover, you say that the code "seems to run", but even after fixing the typos, it bombs on the `bb = forward(b)` line, because you must explicitly specify `reuse_variables()` any time you want to reuse a variable. See my answer for working code.

Answer (score 1):

The following code does what you want:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def forward(inputs):
    init = tf.random_normal_initializer()
    w = tf.get_variable("weights", shape=(3,2), initializer=init)
    return tf.matmul(w, inputs)

with tf.name_scope("group_1"):
    a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(2, 3), name="a")
    b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(2, 3), name="b")
    c = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(2, 3), name="c")
    with tf.variable_scope("foo", reuse=False):
        aa = forward(a)
    with tf.variable_scope("foo", reuse=True):
        bb = forward(b)
        cc = forward(c)

with tf.name_scope("group_2"):
    d = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(2, 3), name="d")
    with tf.variable_scope("foo", reuse=True):
        dd = forward(d)

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    print(bb.eval(feed_dict={b: np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])}))
    for var in tf.all_variables():
        print(var.name)
        print(var.eval())
```

A few important things to understand:

- `name_scope()`affects all ops **except variables created with `get_variable()`**.
- To place a variable in a scope, you need to use a `variable_scope()`. For example, placeholders `a`, `b`, and `c` are actually named `"group_1/a"`, `"group_1/b"`, `"group_1/c"` and `"group_1/d"`, but the `weights` variable is named `"foo/weights"`.
  So `get_variable("weights")` in the name scope `"group_1"` and variable scope `"foo"` actually looks for `"foo/weights"`.

The `all_variables()` function is useful if you are not sure what variables exist and how they are named.